# Ramifications of lack of Brachah for the tribe of Shimon

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, blessing, moshe-rabbeinu, shevatim-12-tribes

I have a hard time understanding Moses' Brochos to the tribes and how it correlates to the actual course of history. As I can see, the interpreters felt the same problem and tried to pick single persons or an occasion that might "justify" Moses' blessing for that tribe.

IIRC, the tribe of Shimon wasn't blessed at all. What are the practical ramifications of that fact - how did it influence its history relative to other tribes that *were* blessed?